# Forgot to unmount local drive's partition during live ubuntu shutdown; now unable to see them in windows 7

Tags: partitioning, mount, windows-7, live-cd, gpt

I wanted to create Raspberry Pi sd card image using "dd" command in linux. 
So, used ubuntu live CD in my Windows 7 laptop.
*During my work I mounted drive "E" to some "/media" folder in ubuntu.*

Then after my task completed I shutdown the machine wout unmounting that drive. After shutdown CD ejected automatically and orange screen stayed for 5 minutes. So, I shut the machine off.

**But now when I started windows 7; its not allowing me to access the "F" drive. It seems that might be it became GPT partition due to mounting in ubuntu. Now I fear to do any trial and error commands execution; as I am not a linux guy.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No, forgetting to  unmount wouldn't have caused anything of that sort, neither prevent access nor changing the partition characteristics. Something else happened, perhaps a wrong dd command? How exactly have you mounted, what dd command, and how does it shows now in Windows, what error message?...

Comment: Without exact commands we can't say for sure, but it sounds like you need to re-install windows, as it's likely you dd'd to the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks @CelticWarrior; I mounted drive "E" to media folder then used command like "dd if=/dev/sdb of=/media/SDC_Backup.img" and now its showing me the file correctly in "E" drive of windows 7. When I open explorer and try to open "F" drive it has no property and when double click it asks to format the drive. Its my commercial machine and I dont have admin rights in Windows 7. Also, 7 has partitions like "C,E and F". Problem is "F" drive is not visible/accessible now.

Comment: As the answer below, you dd'd to the wrong place, deleting everything in /media. No wonder it doesn't open in Windows. The DD command is known as "disk destroyer" for a reason: It takes no prisoners. Once issued there's no turning back. You shouldn't be using it unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's impossible to change a single partition from [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) form to the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) form. MBR and GPT are both partition table types that apply to the *entire disk,* so changing just one partition from MBR to GPT form is impossible. (There is a partial exception in the form of [hybrid MBRs,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) but there's no evidence you have a hybrid MBR, and creating them requires specialized tools that mostly exist on Macs.) Furthermore, even if you had accidentally changed the entire disk from MBR to GPT, that would not affect the data inside any of the partitions. (At least, that change alone would not have such an effect. An accidental MBR-to-GPT conversion could have been done by a program that might *also* have altered the partitions' contents, though.) MBR and GPT both simply describe partition start and end points, as well as provide some additional metadata; filesystem data structures reside entirely within the partitions, and are not affected by partition table type codes.

My suspicion is that you mistyped your `dd` command. Perhaps you mixed up the `if` and `of` options, thus overwriting the contents of your `F:` partition instead of copying them to a file on the `E:` partition, as you intended. Typing `sudo blkid /dev/sdx#` (where `/dev/sdx#` is the identifier for the partition in question) might provide some clues about what's wrong. This command displays basic information on the filesystem used on the partition:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3: UUID="5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea" TYPE="ext4"
```

This example shows an ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sdc3`. Details will differ for an NTFS volume, or even for another ext4 filesystem. Of course, it's also possible that `blkid` won't provide much useful information -- if my hypothesis is correct, then it might provide no output at all, if it can't identify a filesystem on the partition.

In a next-to-worst-case scenario, you might need to recover your data from a backup. Don't have a backup? Then you're into the worst-case scenario, in which your only hope is to use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar to recover your data on a file-by-file basis. This is likely to be tedious and the results are likely to be incomplete. If Windows was installed to the partition, you likely will never be able to boot that installation again, making a re-install necessary. (Do a re-install *after* you recover any personal files you can, though; re-installing will make file-level recovery even harder.)